# 3-key-combination not working

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys

I'm having this weird issue with my laptop. I can not use some of the 3 key combinations for some reason. I can use some off them, for instance, CTRL+Shift+T to re open closed tabs in chrome, but at the same time, I can not use CTRL+Shift+Left_Arrow to select previous word(s) while programming. This is really getting on my nerves, I think this *may* be a hardware issue but I am too afraid to confirm it myself.

If someone can tell me a way to confirm whether this is hardware issue or some problem with windows, I'll appreciate it.

My laptop;

- Haier Y11C
- Intel Core m3 7th gen (1 GHz, 4 cores, 1.6 GHz with boost)
- 8GB of RAM
- 1TB of hard drive
- 4GB of Intel HD Graphics 615

My OS;

- Windows 10 Pro Education 64-bit (Build 17134)

Comment: Tried using an external keyboard? You might have some weird bindings.

Comment: @spikey_richie yeah i tried that, external keyboard works fine.

Comment: Are any of the keys involved in the non-working combinations dual use (e.g. Have a different function printed on the key, usually in a different color)?

Comment: No @TwistyImpersonator, there are no dual uses on these keys.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me as I have bought a new keyboard recently. If you are on windows 10 go to windows setting then devices then typing. Scroll down below until you see advance keyboard settings. Now there you will see override default input method. Try selecting English-US or any other keyboard but the option must not be kept "Use Language list".

This method fixed my 3 key combination issue. Hope it might help.